# Squat form: out or down?

Tags: squats, starting-strength

What's the right to squat: Focus on driving up and down, or on sticking one's backside out?

From what guys at the gym say, and many pictures online, you need to be sticking yourself *out*.  Yet from Starting Strength's instructions: focusing on tightening lower back, chest up, hip drive - it seems to be more of an up down motion, without as much protrusion.  Which is correct? Does the backside need to protrude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cue to stick your butt out is intended to help bring your lower back into proper extension to maintain the *normal anatomical arch*. That means a straight back, not an overextended back.

Actually sticking your butt out can lead to a hyperextended position that is not desirable, but Mark Rippetoe says:

> "an inflexible person may need to *try* to hyperextend just to get to
>   a correct [...] position."

Figure 2-37 from 3rd Edition Starting Strength shows the difference.

So, you are correct, your backside does not need to protrude, but you may need to *try* to make it do so in order to maintain the proper position.